# Regex group in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find some words in my string. Example: {add_First} and/or {ban_1}

Regular expression for first:  `var arr = str.match(/{add_([A-Z]+)}/gi);`

Regular expression for second: `var arr = str.match(/{ban_([0-9]+)}/gi);`

But how to combime both regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/{(add_([A-Z]+)|ban_([0-9]+))}/gi
```

Here is a [Regexper visualisation](http://www.regexper.com/#/%7B%28add_%28%5BA-Z%5D+%29%7Cban_%28%5B0-9%5D+%29%29%7D/gi):

[image]

Comment: And what will you get out of it?

Comment: I assume the OP wants to get a whatever function that will return an array of something like `[1, 'First', 2, 'Second', ...]` or `[[1, 'First'], [2, 'Second'], ...]`. Your regular expression will return the array of full matched groups, i.e. `['{add_First}', '{ban_1}', ...]`.

Comment: @VisioN I'm still not sure what you mean. It appears to me that OP just wants to check whether text exists within a string. If the `str` variable is set to `Hello, {add_First} world!`, for instance, passing in the regular expression from my answer into `str.match(...)` will return an array containing `"{add_First}"`.

Comment: But VisioN is right I can't get an ID using your code? How can I change this?

Comment: str = str.replace(/{(add_([A-Z]+)|ban_([0-9]+))}/gi, function(match, id) {
   //console.log(id);
   var o = Core.get_data_by_id(ex.extensions, id);   
      return (o && o.status == "1") ? o.html : match; 
   });

Comment: @user889349 I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you need to a lookahead/lookbehind (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups).

Comment: I would like to get an array like this: [1, 'First', 2, 'Second', ...]. Now I have: ['{add_First}', '{ban_1}', ...]